# Formula that increases in value every 50

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a range of values, 1..1000, and I want to get the sum where values 1 to 50 are valued at 1, while 51-100 are valued at 2, 101-150 valued at 3...

So I would end up with:

| number | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| .. | .. |
| 49 | 49 |
| 50 | 50 |
| 51 | 52 |
| 52 | 54 |
| .. | .. |
| 99 | 148 |
| 100 | 150 |
| 101 | 153 |
| 102 | 156 |

I came up with this formula:

```
=(FLOOR(A1/50, 1)*50)+(MOD(A1,50)*(FLOOR(A1/50, 1)+1))
```

And it worked until I got to 100... then it falls apart...

[image: actual results of the above formula, compared with desired values]

The 2nd column is what the formula produces, but the 3rd is what I'm expecting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try this `=INT((A1+49)/50)`

It will return 1, 2, 3, etc, for 1-50, 51-100, 101-150...

[image: Result]

**Update**
Yes, you can do this with formulas like

```
=25*(INT((INT((A1-1)/50)*50+49)/50))*(INT((INT((A1-1)/50)*50+49)/50)+1)+(A1-INT((A1-1)/50)*50)*(INT((A1+49)/50))
```

or

```
=25*INT((INT((A1+49)/50)*50+49)/50)*(INT((INT((A1+49)/50)*50+49)/50)+1)-(INT((A1+49)/50)*50-A1)*INT((A1+49)/50)
```

this will work without auxiliary table

Comment: Thanks, that gives the incremental value within those ranges but not the sum (your 3rd column) which is what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @Phill You simply add the increment of the current number to your previous result. e.g. `((51 + 49) / 50) = 2 => 50 + 2 = 52` ; `((52 +49) / 50) = 2 => 52 + 2 = 54` ; `((53 +49) / 50) = 2 => 54 + 2 = 56`

Comment: Ah, I see, I was trying to do it without having to calculate the previous value, but not to worry it works great. Much simplier than my original method. Thanks.

Comment: @Phill Please mark the question as solved.

Comment: @JohnSUN ,,, nice one & is working +10 ☺

Comment: Wow thanks @JohnSUN ! How to upvote more than once :D thanks, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an answer that’s slightly shorter than the ones in [JohnSUN’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1736809/354511#1736813):

```
=A1 + FLOOR((A1-1)/50,1)*(MOD(A1-1,50)+1) + 50*(FLOOR((A1-1)/50,1)*(FLOOR((A1-1)/50,1)-1))/2
```

You say you want to be able to calculate value *N*
without needing to know value *N−1* (and all the preceding values). 
I can do that, and make the formula shorter, by adding a “helper” column. 
If Column `Z` is not being used for anything, set `Z1` to
`=FLOOR((A1-1)/50,1)`,
and then you can compute the value for any row with

```
=A1 + Z1*(MOD(A1-1,50)+1) + 50*(Z1*(Z1-1))/2
```

I can’t explain how it works right now. 
I just played around with it for a while and applied some intuition,
and I came up with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short formula calculating output without neither helper column, neither relying on previous value:
`=LET(groups,INT(([@number]-1)/50),groups*(groups+1)/2*50+(groups+1)*(MOD([@number]-1,50)+1))`

The principle of the formula:
50 * n*(n+1)/2 + mod * (n+1)
where n is the number of complete group of 50 numbers *int((n-1)/50)* and mod is the count of numbers of the last, incomplete group *MOD(n-1,50)+1)*

calculating for e.g. 256:

- 50 * 1 + 50 * 2 + 50 * 3 + 50 * 4 + 50 * 5 + 6 * 6
- = 50 * (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5) + 6 * 6
- = 50 * ( 5 * 6 / 2) + 6 * 6 *(sum of number from 1 to n = n*(n+1)/2)*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 175;
int result = i + (i / 50);
```

result is equal to 178 in this example.

If you were not using an int:

```
float i = 175;
float result = i + (float)Math.Floor((float)i / 50);
```

So I guess the formula would be
X = A + FLOOR(A / 50)

Comment: Even if the mathematical concept is the same, his question is specifically about excel, not C++. Please edit your answer to be on-topic for excel.

Comment: Besides, it’s fairly clear that this is not the result that the OP is looking for. Note that, starting in the 50’s, the desired results start getting *much* bigger than the input values. There’s no way that the result for 175 would be as low as 178.